# Visual Studio extension fails when parsing JSON due to not finding "Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces"

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2022, vsix

I am developing a Visual Studio Extension for VS2022. Part of the functionality of the extension involves parsing JSON. For that, I installed the latest version of System.Text.JSON (7.0.1). However, in the experimental instance, when I attempt to run a task that involves parsing JSON, I get this error:

[image: Image of the error]

I am using .NET Framework 4.7.2. In the VSIX tab of the project properties, I have it set to deploy the VSIX content to an experimental instance for debugging. Furthermore, my debug configuration looks like this - although I have tried tweaking it to get it to work, to no avail.

[image]

I tried a few things. Firstly, I added a reference to Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces 7.0.0 from the NuGet package manager. This didn't help. For context, here's what this part of the CSPROJ looks like

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces">
      <Version>7.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.SDK" Version="15.0.1" ExcludeAssets="runtime">
      <IncludeAssets>compile; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VSSDK.BuildTools" Version="17.4.2119">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Json">
      <Version>7.0.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

I also tried:

- Resetting the Experimental Instance.
- Deleting "bin" and "obj" folders in the solution
- Upgrading to the most recent version of Visual Studio 2022
- Upgrading System.Text.JSON (I actually was trying it with 7.0.0 before, but I upgraded it to 7.0.1)
- Bumping the version of the extension

I would appreciate any help you can give to this struggling extension creator :)

Comment: The error clearly tells you it needs the package `Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces`. That's a dependency of `System.Text.Json` and is installed in your project automatically. I suspect it wasn't deployed along with the other assemblies

Comment: Apologies, @DanielLorenz, but I do not understand your comment. I am deserializing the JSON into a class with three properties - two lists of strings, and one string.

Comment: Resetting, deleting, removing won't fix a missing Nuget error. They can create far more serious problems though

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos do you have any suggestions for ensuring that the dependency is deployed? Also, is there any way to check that this is the case? I checked the bin folder of the solution, and the Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces dll was present...

Comment: It appears that @PanagiotisKanavos was correct. The assembly was not being deployed correctly - a baffling situation, considering that it was declared in the csproj, and present in the bin folder, but not in the extension folder in the experimental instance. I am looking for a better solution than just copying the DLL over.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for this is that by default Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces is suppressed from being included in your VSIX.  This is done by the VS SDK in order to reduce duplicate copies of the assembly from being installed (wasting disk space, as VS already includes a version of this assembly, as well as edge case scenarios where loading from not-the-default path can impact VS performance, e.g. breaking NGEN).

In your case, VS is shipping a copy at version 6.0.0.0, and has a binding redirect from 0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0.  However, your extension depends on 7.0.0.0, which can't be located so it fails to load.

Until VS ships a copy of the 7.0.0.0 version, you'll need to make sure yours is included in your VSIX, and that you provide a code base for it (for example, using the [ProvideCodeBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.providecodebaseattribute?view=visualstudiosdk-2022) attribute).  I think (but haven't verified) that adding this to your project file *after* the VSSDK.targets import might let it be included in the VSIX:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <!-- remove this once VS ships this assembly at the version you need -->
  <SuppressFromVsix Remove="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll" />
</ItemGroup>
```

The other option, of course, is to use an older version of System.Text.Json so that it aligns with the version that VS currently ships.